# One word for a person who sticks with a certain thing/ person/ situation?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a colleague who is working with the same team for 5 years now. I wanted to compliment him by saying:

> He is the kind of person who'd stick with things

How would I do that using a single word?

PS- Apparently, the word "stickler" means something totally different :)

Comment: give a sample sentence or two please

Comment: Please see this guidance from Stack Exchange management regarding [***Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity***](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Answer (score 1):

Dedicated, committed, loyal, determined.

Comment: Agreed ... "loyal" is what I thought of.

Answer (score -1):

Devoted would be the best word to use. It has a more personal connection to what the person is sticking to. It's the word used when describing commitment to faith, spouse, etc.